# Get/post to RESTful web service

Tags: rest, web-services, vb6

I need to do some GETing and POSTing to a RESTful web service from VB6. What is the best and simplest way to do that?

Comment: My condolences for having to consume a webservice in VB6.

Comment: @Ryan, At least it is much better than rewriting several classes from php into vb and then maintaining them. And since I'm making the webservice, it is going to be as simple as possible, ie no xml, json, etc. The response will be just a single short string(one word?) or possibly a number.

Comment: LOL I want to go back to C# (waaaa) LOL

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You'll need to add a reference to the MSXML library:

```
Dim sUrl As String
Dim response As String
Dim xmlhttp

Set sUrl = "http://my.domain.com/service/operation/param"

Set xmlhttp = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
xmlhttp.open "POST", sURL, False
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
xmlhttp.send()

Dim response As String = xmlhttp.responseText

Set xmlhttp = Nothing
```

Comment: And conveniently similar to using XMLHTTPRequest in JavaScript inside Internet Explorer!

Comment: @Justin I don't have MSXML2, I do have MSXML.XMLHTTPRequest, is that similar?

Comment: That code isn't even close to being VB6, but I suppose you should be able to figure it out from that.

Comment: @Bob Riemersma - You're right. I've spent entirely too much time away from it. Hopefully my edits bring it closer in line to correct VB6 syntax.

Comment: How do you pass some data with this code? This snippet just simply calls a service?

Comment: How would this change for JSON?

Comment: @garaber - You wouldn't. Your `responseText` would just be JSON instead of XML.

Comment: I also need to send JSON as well

Comment: I need to send the JSON to the server at this point. I have two keys also that I am currently sending as part of the url

Comment: If createObject function is used, I think there is no need to have reference. Also I don't understand why Server.CreateObject is used, isn't just CreateObject ?

Comment: Server.CreateObject is in ASP.net, in VB6 there is only CreateObject

Comment: @Shafeek - Here's the link for the classic ASP (VB6) Built-in Object: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524786(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: It works!!!!! thanks!!!!.... in my case, there was some missing parenthesis in your code. In the "open" and "header" instruction

Comment: Also, it needs the property "aspcompat="true"" on the page declaration.

Answer (score 15):

I needed this for GET requests in an old legacy application recently, and since the accepted answer doesn't compile I thought I'd post some working code. I'm sure it will help some poor sole using VB6 in the future ;) Here's a nice clean function.

```
Public Function WebRequest(url As String) As String
    Dim http As MSXML2.XMLHTTP
    Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")

    http.Open "GET", url, False
    http.Send

    WebRequest = http.responseText
    Set http = Nothing
End Function
```

And here's example usage:

```
Dim result As String
Dim url As String

url = "http://my.domain.com/service/operation/param"
result = WebRequest(url)
```

Happy VB6ing! :)

Comment: lol. I couldn't agree more. It is the [most dreaded language](https://stackoverflow.com/insights/survey/2017/#technology-most-loved-dreaded-and-wanted-languages) in 2017 after all ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to GET/POST from a REST Web service you can simply write an HTTP Request to the URL of the webservice:

```
http://www.webservicehost.com/webserviceop?<any parameters>
```

If you need to pass complex objects you will need to serialize them and then pass them as parameters

You can then get the HTTP Response in whatever format the Web service decides to return as (JSON, XML, etc)

Comment: Your answer doesn't address how to implement this in VB6.

Comment: I think echo knows the principles, and is looking for specific vb6 advice.

Comment: yup, just the specifics is all I needed. I don't touch VB6 much anymore thankfully, I now work with mostly PHP and some python.

Comment: Then Justin Niessner has the best answer IMO, sorry for the misunderstanding.