# VB6 application calling Rest Service

Tags: web-services, rest, vb6

I have to call a REST service from VB6. I followed this post 
[Get/post to RESTful web service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3516119/get-post-to-restful-web-service) but doesnt able to achieve much.

What I have done so far is :

```
Dim sUrl As String
Dim response As String
Dim xmlhttp

sUrl = "myserviceurl"
xmlhttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.xmlhttp")
xmlhttp.open "GET", sUrl, False
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

Set xmlhttp = Nothing
```

Have added **MSXML6** to my project references.

I get this error :

```
  Object doesnt support this Method..
```

Comment: the string "sUrl" seems to be problem to me. Can you try to put path of actual url?

Comment: .. Its not the problem, coz I can debug after that as well.Sorry I cant put my production url due to some concerns.

Comment: on which line you get error?

Comment: `xmlhttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.xmlhttp")`

Comment: Which windows version you use?

Comment: I am not sure this will solve your problem but try
Dim xmlhttp As MSXML2.XMLHTTP
              Set xmlhttp = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP

Comment: You should post this as anwser :) It worked !!

Comment: i posted answer. Really happy it worked for you. Please accept and upvote if possible :)

Comment: Er, did you try `Set xmlhttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.xmlhttp")` ?  That looks like your actual error to me: no Set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code

```
Dim xmlhttp As MSXML2.XMLHTTP 
Set xmlhttp = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP
```