# I want to Consume RESTful API in VB 6.0 App?

Tags: rest, vb6

how can I Consume RESTful API in VB 6.0 ? like this in C#

```
    public void Test()
    {
        var client = new RestClient("https://id.eta.gov.eg/connect/tok");
        client.Timeout = -1;
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        request.AddHeader("", "");
        request.AddHeader("Cookie", "f5avraaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa_session_=BBEFAJLMEALDGOIKCNAMFDMGKDGAPPDALMALBNBEFIDMAJMABMDDJFPNNHKHKJILANIDIHGMNIBNENGMGMHAMMCGPBMIOLFMEIHFGIJLAMHBFDCMHCOAINNFFHNPBGHO; 3f6bf69972563c3e0e619b78edf73035=569e1386de4bc0689df7968b2bbeb93d; COOKIE=!oWRlbbY/5QvEBq/0gcmF1qcoH9PGNnXCKOVCxQOVimWlCsaMUCv2EV/AgWVgCRbKWYL6NYPVvvBRHNU=");
        request.AddParameter("grant_type", "client_credentials");
        request.AddParameter("client_id", "c-4d80-850f-810ca447");
        request.AddParameter("client_secret", "76-47bb-9507-1da99f40");
        request.AddParameter("scope", "InvoicingAPI");
        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
        Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
    }
```

so i want to call that api from vb6 App .

Comment: recommend you regenerate your client secret...you dont want to post that on SO

Comment: thank you so much , but this Client Secret is fake , for Example only

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3516119/5162073) would be helpful?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get/post to RESTful web service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3516119/get-post-to-restful-web-service)

Comment: If you can consume a C# object from VB6 I recommend writing it all in C# and then just calling it from VB6.